# Wrong keys in foreach loop in my PHP code

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create the array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 39
            [title] => Hello World
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 40
            [title] => Another Title
        )

)
```

But now I am getting this:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39
            [1] => 40
        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello World
            [1] => Another Title
        )

)
```

My PHP code on the server is this:

```
$accountsArray = array();

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

    $accountsArray['ID'][]    = get_the_ID();
    $accountsArray['title'][] = get_the_title();

endwhile;
```

But the keys are the ID and title instead of the 0 and 1 etc.

How to fix this?

Comment: `while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    $accountsArray[]  = ['ID' => get_the_ID(), 'title' => get_the_title()];
endwhile;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$accountsArray = array();
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

$accountsArray[] = array
(
   'ID' => get_the_ID(),
   'Title' => get_the_title()
);

endwhile;
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. I fixed it myself a few while ago. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do vice versa something like as

```
$i = 0;
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

    $accountsArray[$i]['ID']    = get_the_ID();
    $accountsArray[$i]['title'] = get_the_title();
    $i++;

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution without a helper variable e.g. $i

```
$accountsArray = array();

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    $accountsArray[] = array(
        'ID' => get_the_ID(),
        'title' => get_the_title()
    );
endwhile;
```